# How can I change URL and avoid that "?q=" appears?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 + apache2 + php 5.33 + mysql + Drupal 7.

My problem is the URLs used by Drupal are similar to the following one: `http://localhost:8080/drupal72/?q=node/1`.

I want to remove the `?q=node/1` and replace it with some name `/user` or `/book`.

Answer (score 5):

You want to add "Clean URLs" to your installation of drupal, see:

http://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls

Comment: Thanks for this link. I have done the changes in .htaccess file but still no result. I m using it in my localhost machine not on any server.

Comment: @manish nautiyal If you are using Apache, check that the configuration file contains the directive `AllowOverride All` for the directory where Drupal is installed. If it contains `AllowOverride None`, then the directives contained in the .htaccess file are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling clean URLs is the first step you should do. What you would get are URLs that appearsas `http://example.com/node/1` (replace example.com with the domain of your Drupal site). If then you want a URL similar to `http://example.com/books/clean-urls`, then you should install [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto).

> The Pathauto module automatically generates path aliases for various kinds of content (nodes, categories, users) without requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you to get aliases like /category/my-node-title.html instead of /node/123. The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system which the administrator can control.

Comment: thanx. I'll use it but first I use drupal methods.

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu you need to do only two things for clean urls to work first one is

> sudo a2enmod rewrite

This is to enable rewrite module of apache. 
Second thing you need to do is, In your default apache host file which is located at

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

In your file it will say

> AllowOverride None

make it to

> AllowOverride All

as follows.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then restart the server

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

This will make clean urls work in drupal.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you need mod_rewrite for Apache to be enabled to be able to use it. See if you have it enabled in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled, and if you don't see a rewrite.load link there what you need to do is:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

then restart the Apache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Then, as mentioned by kiamlaluno, you need to enable Clean URLs, and install Pathauto and Token modules.